# Overlap problem with Android ListView selector

Tags: android, listview, coding-style, overlap

I am trying to style my ListView with two 9-patch background images (16px * 9px), one dark image for default state and another green image for selected and pressed state.

It works except for just one problem that when I select or press one list item, it seems that the selected item overlap the next one a little bit as I can see some pixels of the green background image is on the top of next item.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found I set a padding there...